# http get with API key

Tags: api, flutter, http, dart, get

i am trying to fetch the data from Api , but this api have an api key.
i have the key but when i try to copy the response body i get this error:

```
E/flutter ( 6014): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 6014): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter ( 6014): ^
E/flutter ( 6014):
```

did i use the key in correct way , if no how to use it??

```
  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
var url =
    'https://www.safalb.com/woocommerce/wp-json/wc/v3/products?Consumer ';
final respones = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(url),
  headers: {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
        'api key'
  },
);
final body = json.decode(respones.body);
print(body);
```

}

Comment: This message means that the body of the text is not json, as you can see in the first line it already indicates to be html, do the following test, decode it in utf8 and print the output, it will probably be another body format other than json.. Ex `print(utf8.decode(respones.bodyBytes));`

Comment: Have you tried to run it by using POSTMAN to check the expected response?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are not checking the status code of the response before decoding the response body. In this case you are getting an error in as an html and trying to decode it from the jsonDecoder.

```
 Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
var url =
    'https://www.safalb.com/woocommerce/wp-json/wc/v3/products?Consumer ';
final response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(url),
  headers: {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
        'api key'
  },
);
if(response.statusCode == 200) {
final body = json.decode(response.body);
print(body); }
else {
   print(response.body)

}
}
```

if you want to test your http response try using RestClient plugin for vs code. [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client). otherwise you can use PostMan to test your http requests [here](https://www.postman.com/)